# How to select element inside button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is, to change i's class (which located inside `button`) on click

```
<button><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i></button>
```

Using js code like below (inside on click function):

```
...
$(this).child("i.fa").removeClass("fa-square-o");
...
```

getting `child is not a function error`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe try $(this + " > i").removeClass("fa-square-o) ... ?
or $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-square-o)

Comment: Did you mean `children` instead of `child`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, really there is no child() method in jQuery.

You may use find() or children() for that.

```
$(this).children("i.fa").removeClass("fa-square-o");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `find()` instead.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).find("i.fa").removeClass("fa-square-o");
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3hs5kdk/)

Answer (score 1):

child is not a function.
try this function:

```
$(this).children("i.fa").removeClass("fa-square-o");
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery accepts a second argument as [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context):

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('i.fa', this).removeClass('fa-square-o');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for jQuery .children() function. If you are trying to call that function from onclick attribute, you have to remember to pass reference to object by using "this" word.

```
<button onclick="removeClass(this)"><i class="fa fa-square-o">test</i></button>

removeClass = function(obj){

     $(obj).children("i.fa").removeClass("fa-square-o");

}
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4wvgvzL9/